# CakePHP Security Levels For Forms

Tags: forms, cakephp

What I should 1st say is that the base of the site is not mine! I have taken over the development of a site to add more to it.

I think I should say that all of my code does work, when logged in. However this page is a public page so to access it you done have to be logged in.

This is all fine (view able to everyone, logged in and public) until you submit a form. This should then save the details you have entered into my database table. This does do that, works fine, but only when your logged in.

For the public, once you click submit, it does not save the data but redirects to a login page.

Are there any defults that could have been set up the do not let everyone use a form unless they are logged in? I have looked at the core.php file but there is nothing about form submits.

Any help most welcome.

Thanks

Glenn.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find answer in the code of action which handles the form. I suppose there is some verification of user authentication in this action. Maybe not right here but in the parent controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you where right about the page having some user authentication. What I did was to check another public controller file and found a beforeFilter() function at the top of the page.

Code is below, hope this might help someone else

```
    function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('*');

}
```

Glenn.